# writer.setAttribute don't trigger a view downcast

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I have a plugin where I do this:

```
model.change(writer => {
   writer.setAttribute("testAtr","testValue",element);
});
```

And that works. If I pretty print my model, I can see the testAtr.

But the problem is that my mtHeaderLine element is not downcasted when i call writer.setAttribute so while my model do change, that change is newer visible in the gui.

My downcast is registered as editor.conversion.for('downcast')
and the downcast does get called when the element is first added to the model.

Don't know if this matter, but my plugin is registered as

```
model.schema.register(mtHeaderLine, {
    inheritAllFrom: '$block',
    allowAttributes: ['testatr']
```

} );

So am I wrong to expect writer.setAttribute to result in a new downcast? And if yes, how should I change attributes on my custom elements so they result in changes to the gui?

The downcast code is

```
editor.conversion.for('dataDowncast').add(downcastElementToElement( { model: mtHeaderLine, 
            view: ( modelElement, viewWriter ) => { 
                const css=modelElement.getAttribute('css');
                const isGhost=modelElement.getAttribute("isghost");
                console.log("dataDowncast::Doing line downcast. css='" + css + "' isGhost=" + isGhost);
                const viewElement=viewWriter.createEditableElement('div',{ 'class': (mtHeaderLine + " " + css) ,isghost: isGhost });
                //              return toWidgetEditable(viewElement,viewWriter );
                return viewElement;
            }
        }));
```

Thanks for the help. I got it to work now. All I had to do was add the line

```
.add(downcastAttributeToAttribute( { model: 'isghost', view: 'isghost' } ))
```

Comment: Did you register downcast for `testAtr` attribute?

Comment: Your question is missing the essential piece, which is the definition of your downcast conversion `editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' )...`.

Comment: The downcast code is newer called when I edit my model. I have a console.log() call in there. But I have added it to the question. I tried to ad it both as for('dataDowncast') for('downcast') and for('editingDowncast').

Comment: @SzymonCofalik Apparently I did not. Newer knew that was explicit needed. I just thought a change to the model, would result in a change to the view.

Comment: I added an answer. If you already read it, I edited it a couple of times with more explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have defined only downcasting for elements. You also need to define downcasting for the attributes. An element is not rebuilt if its attribute has been changed.

Here is a link to docs page where all converter helpers are listed and explained: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcast-converters.html

---

More explanation here:

I admit that naming might be a little confusing and one might think that after specifying `elementToElement` conversion, whenever the element changes it is rebuilt using the `elementToElement` converter.

However, there are actually three types of changes that are downcasted:

- insertions,
- deletions,
- attribute changes (whenever I write change I mean changing, setting and removing an attribute).

*(There are also add marker, remove marker and selection changes but these are not important for this subject.)*

So when a bunch of model changes have been done and downcasting kicks in, the engine checks what has changed:

- insertions - if there is a new element inserted, `elementToElement` downcast is used,
- deletions - these are usually easy and are handled by a default converter - you don't need to provide your own converters in most cases (however some features do, like list plugin),
- and finally attribute changes - if an attribute changed on an existing node, attribute downcast is fired to handle that change.

As you can see, insertions and attribute changes are handled separately.

However, when a new element is inserted with an attribute, both insertion change and attribute change (for the new element) is fired.

So, usually, it is a good idea to handle element insertion in one converter (`elementToElement`) and an attribute change in another one (`attributeToAttribute`). Especially if the element can exist both with or without that attribute. In that case, you can have your attribute conversion logic separated from your element conversion logic.

Comment: btw: The thing that had me confused, was that I original thought that attributeToAttribute would create a (view) AttributeElement.

Comment: Yeah, this is another confusing thing.